# Check if a bitset contains all values of another bitset

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, bitset

I'm trying to create an entity/component system that automatically matches suitable entities suitable systems. I'm using `std::bitset` and `RTTI` to automatically assign a bit value to every component type.

A system is defined like this: `MovementSystem : System<Position, Velocity>`.

`MovementSystem`, in this example, accepts any entity that has both the `Position` and the `Velocity` components (and any other component).

To check if an entity is suitable, I compare the system's bitset to the entity's bitset.

```
// Let's assume there are max 4 components

1          1          0         1        // Entity bitset
^          ^                    ^
Position   Velocity             OtherB

1          1          0         0        // Suitable example system bitset
^          ^
Position   Velocity

1          1          1         0        // Unsuitable example system bitset
^          ^          ^                  // Entity does not have OtherA!
Position   Velocity   OtherA
```

So far, my solution is this one:

`if(entityBitset & systemBitset) == systemBitset)) { /* entity is suitable! */ }`

It *seems* to work, but I found it after doodling bitsets on a whiteboard. Is it correct? Can it be improved any further? (Entities will be created and destroyed an immense amount of times in my games, so performance is very important!)

---

Code is [here](https://gist.github.com/SuperV1234/6891886) if needed (shouldn't be), but it's almost impossible to read.

Comment: I'm sorry but why would a built in stdlib function not work?

Comment: you need to use the XOR operator (I think it is `^`)

Comment: @aaronman: function for what? Elaborate

Comment: @SJuan76: I tried messing around with XOR but couldn't get it to work. Should I XOR the entity bitset with the system bitset or viceversa? And should I `.all()` or `.any()` the XOR result?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo sorry I think I misread it

Comment: @VittorioRomeo in your title you say check if two bitsets are equal why can't you just use `==`

Comment: @aaronman: That's not what I say in my title and could you please read the question in its entirety?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo you can't force me to answer your question ;)

Comment: @aaronman: I'm not trying to do that, and I appreciate that you're trying to help. But it's the second time your comment is irrelevant to the question, so I was just suggesting you to read the question completely before trying to help again.

Comment: `(systemBitset&~entityBitset).none()` won't be faster. You can't expect any significant gains compared to what you have.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: alright, this is what I was looking for. Can you please re-post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: @TemplateRex: `a == b` is not equal to `(a & b) == b`.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are the same, `a XOR b` will return `0`. In other case, at least one bit will be `1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your check

```
(a & b) == b;     // check whether b is a subset of a
```

checks whether `b` is a subset of `a`, or equivalent, whether `a` contains/includes `b`. Note that you are creating one temporary followed by the break-early `operator==`.

This is equivalent to checking whether the difference of `b` and `a` is empty (note the order!)

```
(b & ~a).none();
```

This will be equally fast: a temporary followed by a break-early `.none()`

Given the interface of `std::bitset`, this is as fast you can get. The problem with `std::bitset` is that all its bitwise members (`&`, `|`, `^` and `~` loop over every word. The early termination operations like `none()`, `any()`, `==` or `<`, cannot be intertwined with them. This is because `std::bitset` does not expose the underyling word storage so you cannot perform the iteration yourself.

However, if you would write your own bitset class, you could write a special-purpose `includes()` algorithm that loops over each of the words, doing the `&` until you break-early

```
// test whether this includes other
bool YourBitSet::includes(YourBitSet const& other) const {
    for (auto i = 0; i < NumWords; ++i)
        if ((other.word[i] & ~(this->word[i])) != 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

A similar algorithm missing from `std::bitset` would be `intersects()`, to efficiently test `(a & b) != 0`. Currently you have to first do bitwise and, and then the test for zero, whereas that would be more efficiently done in one loop. If `std::bitset` ever gets updated, it would be nice if they include `includes()` and `intersects()` primitives.

Comment: I know it has an equality operator. My question is about the correctness of my solution and possible ways of improving it. In fact, I already use the equality operator in my solution: `if(entityBitset & systemBitset) == systemBitset))`

Comment: how is it the same? `a=1110, b=1100` - `a == b == false` - `(a & b) == b == true`